# How to do LAN search similar to Netscan in Windows?

Tags: networking

I use Netscan softwar to search the available computers with the shared items in microsoft windows. I could give it an IP address range and it retured the available IP address.

In ubuntu is there such a way to scan the network ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a command line utility for that, [nbtscan](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nbtscan), it's available from the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install nbtscan
```

Answer (score 10):

[`nmap`](https://nmap.org/book/man.html)! It's the definitive tool for network discovery (among other things). You can install it from the repositories using

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

After that, you can execute

```
nmap 192.168.1.0/24
```

to reveal services on your subnet, assuming you are on the `191.168.1.0/24` subnet. For a more detailed report, you can type

```
sudo nmap -sS -O 192.168.1.0/24
```

Answer (score 4):

Netscan (for windows) is a very handy tool for browsing lan. There is a similar application for linux too, named ---ShareScanner (netscan for linux). You can download it [here on SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharescanner)

The site contains 32 and 64 bit debian and rpm packages for easy installation. It is actually a GUI for smbclient.

[image: ShareScanner]

Answer (score 0):

[**AngryIP Scanner**](http://angryip.org/w/Download)

There is no question about it. It's much closer to netscan and not in beta like sharescanner.

I just had the same question, and tried all out by now.

Comment: http://angryip.org/w/Download

Comment: oh, yes... Angry IP Scanner is in beta too for ubuntu x64, but it works. sharescanner unfortunately returns nothing to me and has less features.